# ASP.Net logout code block

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

I need a good logout code block for asp.net.  Currently after you logout you can hit the back button and continue using the site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that the session is abandoned and call the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` method as shown below:

```
private void Logout()
{
  Session.Abandon();
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Forms Authentication, you would just do:

```
System.Web.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Without more information I can't be more specific.