# Which is the best way to implement a logoff button in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, logout

Which is the best way to implement a logoff button in Asp.Net?

I am using Forms Authentication.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/981571/102112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this with forms auth:

```
private void lbSignOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Profile profile = Session["Profile"] as Profile;
    Logger.LogInfoMessage("Logging off user: " + profile.UserName);

    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect(Constants.DefaultPage);
}
```

Comment: When I call Session.Abandon(), it also clears the Session State?

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="MasterLoginStatus" runat="server" />
```

Comment: No.  That wasn't specified as a requirement.  I'm not sure - I don't use Session State.

Answer (score 0):

is Google broken? "asp.net membership provider logout" -> http://forums.asp.net/t/1260615.aspx

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Roles.DeleteCookie();
    Session.Clear();
}
```

Comment: a 30 second search before posting a question is a valid thing to ask. If you want people to put the effort into answering your question you can at least put the effort into looking for the answer yourself

Comment: I agree @adam straughan, but I trust this communitie, and I wanted to discuss about it. To find not a way to do it, but the best, simple, implemention. Thanks for the link.

Comment: yes there is, just try and stay clear of http://thedailywtf.com/ for for example solutions :-)